# Can somebody please explain why i can not assign a variable to be a reversed list?

Tags: list, variables

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

reversed_list = my_list.sort(reverse=True)
print(reversed_list)

When i type this code python returns the word "None" and i can not figure out why i can't assign a variable to act as a reversed list. An explanation or a solution for this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The method `sort()` does not return anything. Instead, it changes the list in place. So the correct code would be:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
reversed_list = my_list.copy()
reversed_list.sort(reverse=True)
print(reversed_list)
```

If you don't need both lists, you can avoid copying and do the sorting on `my_list` instead, thus saving some memory.

Answer (score 0):

U can use `sorted()` if u don't wanna change ur list object. `sorted()` function can sort any iterable & return a list of items in that iterable sorted manner.

Eg. `sorted('abicd', reverse=True)` will return `['i', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']`

Sort changes ur list object in place & doesn't return anything i. e, `None` in python.

U can better code it like:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

reversed_list = sorted(my_list, reverse=True) 
print(reversed_list)
```